# Fix height style and when onclick expand div

Tags: javascript, css

On picture below, I have 4 different images inside div

- With the same width and height and
- These divs must have width and height property dynamically which depends on screen height and width.
- Each div must have half of screen height and width.

When click on any div, that div must expand depends on the position of it. If it is positioned at right-top so it should expand to left-bottom with an animation and other divs should be hidden. Finally expanded div should have full height and width 100%. I tried something but it is not satisfied. I just need logic and expand animation type.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```js
$('.box').on('click','.box__inner',function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.box--active').removeClass('box--active');
  $(this).addClass('box--active');
}).on('click','.box--active',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('box--active');
});
```

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}

.box {width:100%; height:100%;position:relative;outline:1px solid blue;}
.box__inner {position:absolute;min-width:50%;min-height:50%;outline:1px solid red;text-align:center;background-color:white;transition:all .1s ease;}
.box__inner.left {left:0;}
.box__inner.right {right:0;}
.box__inner.top {top:0;}
.box__inner.bottom {bottom:0;}
.box__inner.box--active {min-width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__inner left top">Left top</div>
  <div class="box__inner right top">Right top</div>
  <div class="box__inner left bottom">Left bottom</div>
  <div class="box__inner right bottom">Right bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was preparing jsfiddle but you already solved my problem. Thank you, thats what I want.